# Write a Positive definite Matrix as $B^T B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

I came across this problem:

Let $A$ (symmetric) be a positive definite matrix. Prove that there exist $n$ linearly independent vectors 
$x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ such that $A_{ij} = x_i^T x_j$. (Hint: Use the spectral theorem and the fact that all eigenvalues of $A$ are greater than zero to find a matrix $B$ such that $A = B^T B$.)

I have no idea. Could someone please show me show to show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A = X D X^t = X \sqrt{D} \sqrt{D}^t X^t.$$

Comment: Can you explain more? Where did we use the fact that A is positive definite and how did we use the spectral theorem with the eigenvalues and all that?

Comment: The first equality is the spectral theorem, the second needs positivity.

Comment: Oh I see, the first one is indeed spectral theorem. However, I don't quite see where and how the second equality comes from. It certainly is in the correct form, though. All positive definite means is x^T A X > 0. So how did we use it in the second equality?

Comment: $D$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. Can you take square roots of negative numbers?

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant. Thank you!